# Workflow to send E-mail when a list item is updated

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, list, workflow

I am trying to create a workflow for a list where in if one of the current items value is modified a E-mail should go to the person who has create a list item. below is what I have tried. Please advice any correction needed.

Set workflow status to started
then wait for X (current item) to equal Y (value, which is person name from a group)
then wait for status (current item) to equal in progress (drop down)
then Email current item: createdby
the set workflow status to completed

after publishing this workflow I am not getting any email.

Answer (score 1):

One different approach i can think of is to create another field isEmailSend(boolean) in the list which will be hidden in all forms and it will be false by default. Trigger your workflow on item updated.Check your condition and if isEmailSend is false and if it is satisfied then update the isEmailSend flag to true and end workflow.

Use this approach if your wait logic is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot of mixed success with the "Wait for" commands. Your other option (what I typically do) is fire the workflow on item update/edit, and check each condition in this logic as opposed to using "waits".

Answer (score 0):

You can add ItemUpdated/ItemUpdating event to your custom list and send emails from this event. You can also add your custom logic in the event.